# Docker and php-cli

Tags: php, linux, bash, docker, server-administration

I have installed *PHP 7* (php-fpm and php-cli) and my app is working fine with new *PHP*, but tests (**phpunit**) don't because some extensions aren't updated yet.

So I'm thinking to use/create some docker container with *PHP 5.6* that would 
replace my system's (host) *php-cli*.

For example, if I build container called `php56` from *Dockerfile* that looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
RUN  apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y php5-cli
ENTRYPOINT ["php"]
```

and run:

```
sudo docker run -it php56 -v
```

I'm getting version info from **Docker** container, so docker's *php-cli* 5.6 is working. So I wan't to put `docker run` command in

```
/usr/bin/php
```

so that host use *php-cli* from docker container. (then *php -v* would give me *PHP 5.6* info not *PHP 7.0* version info)

It's not best example, but I hope that you guys will understand what I'm trying to do. If it's not possible to solve it like this, please recommend me other solution.

Comment: What do you mean "put `sudo ...` *in* `/usr/bin/php`"?

Comment: If I run `php` in terminal, `docker run` command is executing.
Basically I'm trying to replace host php-cli with php-cli from docker container.

Comment: How do you know that *"my app is working fine with new PHP"* if you aren't running your unit-tests on the same version?

Comment: I don't get any warning/error from php-fpm, all features are working as expected. PHP-fpm 7 and PHP-cli 5.6 would be just temporary solution (on my local dev machine), so I can run tests until extensions are updated. Of course, PHP seven won't be on production until all tests pass.

Comment: What's your question about this? Anything not working with the given approach? Also, if "extensions aren't updated yet", what's the exact problem with them?

Comment: You try to run php execution from docker on host environment?? It  contradicts with the idea of containers itself. When you run smth. inside the container it assumes that the execution environment also belongs to this container.
Now, what you want is to mount your app(php scripts folder) as a persisten volume to your 5.6 container and obtain test results from it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something that looks like what you're looking for: https://github.com/jclaveau/docker-php-multiversion

This adds a php shell script which will run a docker image containing all available PHP versions since 5.6.

You can then run `php 5.6 vendor/bin/phpunit` or `php 7.4 vendor/bin/phpunit`, etc.

I embedded it inside a Docker image after a crash of my SSD where I lost all my php.ini configuration so as long as you have Docker.io installed, it would work